# Deploying a Rails 3.1 app to subdirectory in Apache WITHOUT Passenger

Tags: windows, ruby-on-rails-3, apache

Alright, I've been fighting with this all day, so I figure it's time to throw my question out into the masses of Rails users out there and see if anyone can help. :)

I'm restricted to using a Windows box as a server and I have XAMPP running, serving up a static site from htdocs. I also am running a couple of instances of Thin server off of ports 5000 and 5001 to serve up two Rails apps. I'm trying to set up a reverse proxy through Apache so that users can go to http://mydomain.com/app1 or http://mydomain.com/app2. Here's my proxy.conf file:

```
<Proxy *>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from All
</Proxy>

ProxyVia On
ProxyPass /app1 http://localhost:5000/app1
ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://localhost:5000/app1
ProxyPass /app2 http://localhost:5001/app2
ProxyPassReverse /app2 http://localhost:5001/app2

ProxyPreserveHost On
```

The apps seem to work fine as far as raw content is concerned; however, despite setting ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] to '/app1' in the environment file for app1 and to 'app2' in the environment file for app2, the javascript, stylesheet, and image tags do not prepend '/app1' or '/app2' to the HREF and SRC attributes of their tabs, resulting in no styling, scripting, or images. I've scoured the internets and tried everything I could find, but nothing seems to works. I have a feeling I'm missing something really basic and I just hope someone can help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<Proxy *>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from All
</Proxy>

ProxyPreserveHost On

<Location /app1>
  ProxyPass http://localhost:5000/app1
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:5000/app1
</Location>
<Location /app2>
  ProxyPass http://localhost:5001/app2
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:5001/app2
</Location>
```

Comment: Thanks, tried this and it didn't work. I'm think the problem is less with Apache and more with the asset paths within Rails. It's as if even though the application is served from http://localhost:5001/app1, the public folder is still served from http://localhost:5001/